# Trigger workflow from CEWP button

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a site workflow, now I need to trigger this manually when a button in Content Editor Web Part(CEWP) is clicked. How can I trigger it from a CEWP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt find easy way of triggering site workflow from CEWP(using javascript) so i made a custom list to get updated with required parameter on click of the CEWP button( http://ishaalan.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/adding-an-item-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-javascript/ ). And made list worflow associate with that list to get triggered when a new item was added.It solved my problem.Thanks @dotsa for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly start Workflows from Javascript ( inside CEWP ) using 2010 client object model. But you can always call a web service:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/4-clicks-or-1-using-jquery-to-start-a-sharepoint-workflow.aspx

or use spservices

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow&referringTitle=Workflow

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.ch/2015/10/sharepoint-launch-site-workflow-from.html

It explains how to attachworkflow to any button.